# How to output a file to a specific folder in Lua?

Tags: lua

If I have a string of text `"Testing"` and I am in the working directory `C:/home/files/` how can I output to the directory `C:/home/files2/` ?

My current code is:

```
file = io.open("test.lua", "w", "C:/home/files2/")
file:write("Testing")
file:close()
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `io.open("C:\\home\\files2\\test.lua", "w")`

Comment: Does this work for you? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JasonIvey Its suppose that all folders already exisyst. Lua has not standart way to create directories because C library does not this either

Comment: The directory already exists. However the edits do not take place. The file also already exists with text, "Unedited," When I run, it doesn't change to "Testing."

Comment: @JasonIvey - Run `file = assert(io.open("C:\\home\\files2\\test.lua", "w")); `.  What is your error message?

Comment: No error output.

Answer (score 2):

Lua supports standard path specifications.
If you want file in subdirectory of the working directory, you prepend the filename with the folder name:

```
f=io.open('folder/file','w');
```

You can use double dot sequency to specify the upper directory in the relative path:

```
f=io.open('../files2','w')
```

At least on linux, you can use absolute paths:

```
f=io.open('/home/username/folder/folder/file,'w')
```

As with many command line applications, the folders must exist before file creation is attempted.

You can quickly verify success of opening file by checking the value of `f`:

```
print(f)
--output
file (0xb4acf0)
```